# Scrapy login to site Unsuccessful

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm currently scraping a site which requires I login to view certain info
I've gone through  a bunch of s/o's and other forums, but none proved helpful.

this is my current code:

```
class Test(scrapy.Spider):
    name= 'alpha'

    start_urls =['https://www.spapartsvortex.eu/customer/account/login/']

    def parse(self,response):
        soup = Soup(response.text, 'lxml')
        token =soup.find('input',{'name':"form_key"}).get('value')
        print(token)
        body= {
            'form_key': token,
            'login[username]': "email",
            'login[password]': "password",
            'send': ''
        }
        body = json.dumps(body)
        yield scrapy.Request(
            response.url,
            body=body,
            callback=self.start,
            method='POST',
            headers={
            'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; Googlebot/2.1; http://www.google.com/bot.html) Chrome/W.X.Y.Z‡ Safari/537.36 ",
            'origin': 'https://www.spapartsvortex.eu'})

    def start(self,response):
        if 'My Account' in response.text:
            url ='https://www.spapartsvortex.eu/categories?limit=all'
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url,
                callback=self.parseLevel0)
        else:
            open_in_browser(response)
            print('Login unsuccessful')
```

Comment: Without login credentials how would anyone experience where you are going wrong? At first glance I could find two major flaws in your script. You should use this url for post requests `https://www.spapartsvortex.eu/customer/account/loginPost/` and kick out this `body = json.dumps(body)`. However, the implementation should be more like `yield scrapy.FormRequest(self.post_url,formdata=data,callback=self.start)` instead.

Comment: @SIM You dont expect me to place my login credentials here, do you?
and secondly, I tried this method you talked of first, and it still gives the same result as the one in the question.

Comment: I was talking about pseudo credentials for any pseudo account. Btw, did you include headers while complying with my suggested way? Thanks.

Comment: @SIM no I didnt, maybe I'll try that thanks

Comment: @SIM it didnt work out, thanks for your time though

Comment: Okay, try adding this `referer: https://www.spapartsvortex.eu/customer/account/login/` within headers while sending post requests.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out how to make this work,
I signed in to the site using selenium, then transferred cookies from webdriver to other scrapy requests.